# Intel server board s2600cw2r boot from nvme?

Tags: ssd, intel, pci-express, nvme

I have upgraded BIOS to 19 for supporting efi boot, but I can't see my nvme ssd in the boot manager yet.

Comment: Is a UEFI supporting OS installed on it?

Answer (score 1):

That systemboard, though reasonably new, is based on the Intel C612 chipset which only supports PCIe 2.0 (the systemboard itself does support PCIe 3.0 but not via the chipset) - while PCIe-based NVMe requires native PCIe 3.0 support - so the problem could well be that sorry.